# Unable to acces individual columns after pagination implementation Vue Vuex

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

So i have been trying to put data from my database in a tabel. It has worked before but when i implemented pagination i suddenly wasnt able to retrieve the data i was able to get before. I tried multiple was but not been able to figure it out.

A screenshot of my vuedeveloper tool:
[image]

my store.js action that i changed:

```
    getLogs({commit}, {url = null} ={}){
      url = url || '/get-log'
      commit('setLogsLoading', true)
      return axiosClient.get(url).then((res) => {
        commit('setLogsLoading', false);
        commit("setLogs", res);
        return res;
      });
    },
```

my store.js mutation that i changed:

```
   setLogs: (state, api_logs) => {
      state.api_logs.links = api_logs.data.links;
      state.api_logs.data = api_logs.data;
    },
```

How i used to get data into the table was by call {{log.RESPONSE}}

```
              <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
              <tr v-for="log in logs.data" :key="log">
                <td class="w-1/15 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6 lg:pl-8">{{
                    log.APIGROUPNO
                  }}
                </td>
                <td class=" px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.DATETIMEEXECUTED }}</td>
                <!--                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.JSONBDY }}</td>-->
                <td class="break-all px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.RESPONSE}}</td>
                <td class="break-all px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500"><span
                  class="bg-red-100 text-red-800 text-xs font-semibold mr-2 px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded dark:bg-red-200 dark:text-red-900">Error</span>
                </td>
                <td class="relative  py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6 lg:pr-8">
                  <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">View<span
                    class="sr-only">, {{ log.APIGROUPNO }}</span></a>
                </td>
                <td class="relative  py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6 lg:pr-8">
                  <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span
                    class="sr-only">, {{ log.APIGROUPNO }}</span></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
```

I cant seem to pin point the problem no matter what i try i get the error back cannot read properties of undifined

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the v-for loop I saw that I was looping through `logs.data` but it had to be `logs.data.data` instead ...